# scipy.stats.nanemean documentation?

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

Was trying to find the reference documentation of `scipy.stats.nanmean`, but the links from Google now get redirected to the main Scipy entry page, and searching for `stats` then `nanmean` draws a blank.  Is this a temporary website glitch, or has something major changed in Scipy?

Comment: I don't know why they were not listed in the stats module-level documentation, but they will be in the next release of scipy: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/2540

Answer (score 2):

Can't find it in the documentation, but the help system built into scipy gives what I was looking for:

```
from scipy import stats
stats.nanmean ?
```